# R: Sums of differences between functions of consecutive values

Tags: r, functional-programming, iteration

This is one of those questions where I am quite certain I will be embarrassed by the answer. You may imagine me smacking my forehead, preemptively.

I have an over-arching function to create a list of the outputs of a large number of functions, each applied to one column of a data frame, in a one-to-one manner. Each column function is different, but they all have a common structure: they take the form f(X) = sum(f1(X) - f2(lag(X)), i.e., they are sums of differences between functions of consecutive terms. The f1's and f2's are not -- well, not generally or necessarily -- the same either within or between columns, and in every case at least one of them is non-linear.

The X's are not time series and I would prefer not to make them time series. They are just sequences. You can think of them as being indexed by length(sequence) - row number + 1. But all I have been able to get out of my functions, real or toy, are NAs and error messages.

An toy example is below. I have tried many variants of this toy function and none of them work. I am pretty sure I should not have to wrap each individual column function in a for loop, or even a purrr function. Imagine the example below has 300 rows, all different, but all with the structure given. What is an efficient way to get all of these sequences of sums of differences of functions, where the code defining the subsidiary functions of each column function has been written? Something R-ish and functional?

(By efficient, I mean efficient for the programmer. The functions that compose the list were a lot of work, but the data set is not so big that the computations are likely to be burdensome.)

```
library(tidyverse)

A = 2:6
B = 2:6
tb <- tibble(A, B)
alpha <- beta <- mu <-0.5
oneDay <- with(tb[1:4,], list(
  var1 <- sum(A - (lag(A) -1)^2, rm.na = TRUE), 
  var2  <- sum(exp(-alpha*(B)) - exp(-beta(lag(B)- mu), rm.na = TRUE))
  )

oneDay
[[1]]
[1] NA

[[2]]
[1] NA
```

Comment: I am not exactly clear about the question you should use `na.rm = TRUE` and not `rm.na`. Can you show your expected output ?

Comment: What @RonakShah said and also, your code was giving errors, once I corrected it to `var2  <- sum(exp(-alpha*(B)) - exp(-beta*(lag(B)- mu)), na.rm = TRUE)` it wouldn't return `NA`'s.

Comment: With the comments made by

Comment: Of course! Thanks @RonakShah! Thanks @RuiBarradas! It appears that my brain was broken at the time of this post. <blushes>